# why when unchecking checkbox - checkedChanged event doesn't execute

Tags: asp.net

In my function `createCheckboxes`()  I dynamically create checkboxes - all of them with assigned `checkedChanged` event.

In the event handler i test if the checkbox is checked and if so I sore the value attribute in a session.

But for example if a client decides to check one checkbox and alue is added  to the session, but then he suddenly decides that he  want to uncjheck that checbox - so I  should delete this value from the arraylist and then from the session.

**The big problem is that it seems that when unchecking the Checkedchanged event handler is never executed and this code is never executed**

```
else if (!chk.Checked)
        {
             lblProba.Text += "You wll be delited";
            for (int i = 0; i < element.Count; i++)
            {

                if (element[i].ToString().Equals(chk.InputAttributes["value"]) == true)

                    element.Remove(element[i]);
            }

        }
```

My full code

---

```
        protected void checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            element.Add(chk.InputAttributes["value"]);

        }

        else if (!chk.Checked)
        {
             lblProba.Text += "You wll be delited";
            for (int i = 0; i < element.Count; i++)
            {

                if (element[i].ToString().Equals(chk.InputAttributes["value"]) == true)

                    element.Remove(element[i]);
            }

        }

            for (int t = 0; t < element.Count; t++)
        { 
            Session["chk"]+= element[t].ToString(); 

        }


}
        protected void createCheckboxes()
        {
            chkddlchange = true;
            int numTourists = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
            {

                Label myLabel = new Label();
                myLabel.ID = "lblAccomodation" + (i + 1).ToString();
                myLabel.Text = "Настаняване Турист" + (i + 1).ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myLabel);
                DropDownList myDropDownList = new DropDownList();
                myDropDownList.ID = "ddlTourist" + i.ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=excursion;Trusted_Connection=true";
                string query =
          "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                try
                {

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rd= cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int s = 0;


                    while (rd.Read())
                    {   
                        CheckBox mycheckbox = new CheckBox();
                        mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                       mycheckbox.Text = rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString();
                       mycheckbox.InputAttributes.Add("value", rd["Extra_Charge_ID"].ToString());

                       mycheckbox.AutoPostBack = true;
                       mycheckbox.EnableViewState =true ;
                       mycheckbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkChanged);
                       Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);


                        s++;

                    }

                       //myche.Add(mycheckbox.Items[s].Text);


                }//End of try

                catch (Exception ex)
                { }


            }//end of for


        }




    }
}
```

Comment: You should create the checkboxes only if there was no PostBack otherwise you're probably losing the ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

Have you mentioned `Autopostback=true` while creating  your checkbox? If not than please do it and see if it works or not.